# Python: OAuth Library

Tags: python, oauth, yahoo

Is there a full flegged python library for oauth? I haven't found any that handle reissuing of oauth tokens once they expire (Step 5 on the [Yahoo OAuth flow](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html)).

So what is the most complete? I tried the one from [oauth.net](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/python/oauth/), and it doesn't handle `oauth_session_handle` which the oauth spec says is required if the endpoint returns it (like yahoo does).

So, what library should I be using? Are they all incomplete and I have to do it on my own?

Comment: I built a package to make it super easy and snappy https://github.com/evansmwendwa/python-socialite

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think Leah Culver's [python-oauth](http://www.python-oauth.com/) (that you've already found) is the best starting point even though it's not complete.

Leah has a mirror up on github which would make it easy to collaborate: http://github.com/leah/python-oauth/tree/master/oauth/

**Update**: As it stands today, it looks like SimpleGeo's [python-oauth2](http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) is the best starting point.

Comment: Thanks. I forked her repo and am waiting on a pull request. http://github.com/ptarjan/python-oauth

Comment: Thanks for adding to it! Helps me too as I'm using it for several projects — much appreciated!

Comment: Anything new to report since the last update?

Comment: I like the Requests library. I was wondering if there is a unofficial standard library, rather popular library.

Comment: Anyone who is looking for a modern and updated library can check Authlib: https://authlib.org/

Comment: I built a easy to use package for that https://github.com/evansmwendwa/python-socialite

Answer (score 11):

[Rauth](https://rauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is the new best answer as far as I'm concerned. Wraps [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library and it's well-maintained.

Answer (score 4):

[OAuth](http://oauth.net/code/) official website recommends both [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth) and [oauthlib](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib). Quoting them regarding **rauth**:

> Max Countryman maintains the rauth and it is considered the most up-to-date and unit-tested implementation of OAuth for Python.

Regarding **oauthlib**:

> Another great library is OAuthlib which implements the latest RFC, including client and server.

***UPDATE: Feb 9th, 2019***

Both libraries are still mentioned in the [OAuth recommended libs for Python](https://oauth.net/code/python/), but looking at their Github page, **oauthlib** has been more frequently maintained.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Mike Knapp's library on [GitHub](https://github.com/mikeknapp/AppEngine-OAuth-Library).
Nice and simple, no install needed. And works on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

Use Kenneth Reitz's awesome [requests](http://python-requests.org) library along with the [requests-oauth](https://github.com/maraujop/requests-oauth) plugin linked off of http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/out-there/

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer to the 9-year-old question. The following are libraries for OAuth 2.0 and [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) and sample implementations written in Python. Note that they use [Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/) as a backend service.

1. authlete-python : library for Python ([GitHub](https://github.com/authlete/authlete-python), [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/authlete/))
2. authlete-python-django : library for [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/authlete/authlete-python-django), [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/authlete-django/))
3. [django-oauth-server](https://github.com/authlete/django-oauth-server/) : sample implementation of an authorization server
4. [django-resource-server](https://github.com/authlete/django-resource-server/) : sample implementation of a resource server

The question was posted in 2009. Since then, many important specifications have been developed. The following are some examples.

- 2012, Oct - [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework
- 2012, Oct - [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750), The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage
- 2014, Nov - OpenID Connect [Core 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html)
- 2014, Nov - OpenID Connect [Discovery 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html)
- 2014, Nov - OpenID Connect [Dynamic Client Registration 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html)
- 2015, Sep - [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636), Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients
- 2018, Oct - Financial-grade API (FAPI) Implementer's Draft 2 ([Part 1](https://openid.net/specs/openid-financial-api-part-1-ID2.html), [Part 2](http://openid.net/specs/openid-financial-api-part-2-ID2.html))
- 2019, Feb - OpenID Connect Client Initiated Backchannel Authentication Flow - [Core 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-client-initiated-backchannel-authentication-core-1_0.html)
- 2019, Aug - [RFC 8628](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8628), OAuth 2.0 Device Authorization Grant
- (Draft) - [OAuth 2.0 Mutual TLS Client Authentication and Certificate-Bound Access Tokens](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-oauth-mtls/?include_text=1)

Now the volume of specifications related to OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect is huge, full-fledged implementations are rare. For example, at the time of this writing (Aug 20, 2019), the number of [certified OpenID Provider implementations that support Financial-grade API (FAPI)](https://openid.net/certification/#FAPI_OPs) is just 4. Also, the number of [certified OpenID Provider implementations](https://openid.net/certification/#OPs) that support Basic OP, Implicit OP, Hybrid OP, Config OP, Dynamic OP and Form Post OP is 5. (Authlete is the only implementation that is included in both)

The following are some consideration points for OAuth 2.0 implementations:

1. RFC 7636 support (important for security)
2. OpenID Connect support (or just OAuth 2.0?)
3. Financial-grade API (FAPI) support, if you need higher security. See *"[Financial-grade API (FAPI), explained by an implementer](https://medium.com/@darutk/financial-grade-api-fapi-explained-by-an-implementer-d09fcf2ff932)"* for technical details.